# При отправке curl периодически получаю ошибку Internal Server Error

Tags: php, curl

До сегодняшнего дня все работало.
Но сегодня от утра периодически получаю ошибки при работе с таким кодом.
Сам код может отработать 5 - 6 - 7 раз а на 8 получу ошибку 500 Internal Server Error
А бывает и со второго или первого раза получаю такую ошибку.
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? От утра ищу выход и не в какую.

```
$request_params = [
    'copy_history_depth' => '1'
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getById');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($request_params).'&v=6.76');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$wall_get = curl_exec($ch);
$wall_get = json_decode($wall_get,true);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($wall_get);
echo '</pre>';
```